# [homework][Java] Finding the largest combination of numbers out of 5 integer inputs?

Tags: java

This is for a homework assignment we have to do in class. 
As the title says, I have to find a way to figure the largest combination of numbers given 5 user inputs.
IE if the user inputs 5,6,3,4,2 then the program will find the largest number, so 65432.

The one catch is that since we're only so far in the class, we're not allowed to use arrays, strings, or loops. Basically we can only use operators and if statements. 
How would I go about building a program that doesnt include an excessive amount of "if" statements?

EDIT: basically I was aiming for something along these lines

```
if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3 && num1 >= num4 && num1 >= num5){
        numV1 = num1;
        if (num2 >= num3 && num2 >= num4 && num2 > num5){
         numV2 = num2;
        if (num3 >= num2 && num3 >= num4 && num3 > num5){
        numV2 = num2;
        if (num4 >= num3 && num4 >= num3 && num4 > num5){
         numV2 = num2;
        if (num5 >= num2 && num5 >= num3 && num5 > num4){
        numV2 = num2;
```

and so on and so forth, but this seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: Well, since your professor took away most of the shiny toolbox, I'm afraid all you're left with is excessive amounts of `if` statements...

Comment: I really don't understand what teh phrase `include an excessive amount of "if" statements` . Unnless it is 20837 if's , no issue

Comment: @Coffee: "How would I go about building a program that doesnt include an excessive amount of "if" statements?" in the OP is exactly what you propose. He is trying to find an alternative to ugly code, and I for one think it's admirable. Too bad that, as Makoto says, all the shiny tools are taken away.

Comment: I'd scratch it out on paper. This is more of a logic/math problem than code per se

Comment: Sure, but SO is not only for code problems. It is for *programming* problems. Construction of an algorithm is a programming problem.

Comment: Why do teachers teach bad coding practice? This escapes me.

Comment: Given that the question is closed, I'll post here: If each input is a single digit, then you probably noticed that the biggest number is the one with the largest of the five digits in front. So it's basically a sort. What you want to do is take a sort algorithm (any sort algorithm, really; I vote for selection sort), and unroll it. It will be painful. It's bad code, and your professor is a sadist. But that's the only way to do it with no loops and no recursion. If "input" is possibly larger than a digit... it is beyond sadism.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi  - That's up for debate though.. exercise is exercise I gues

Comment: This is not exercise. This is teaching things wrong. The correct solution to this problem is an ArrayList and Collections.sort(). It's like teaching to paint in an art class with a car paint sprayer.

Comment: @Coffee: A futile exercise, for sure. Or "how to survive dull workplaces" exercise. If it is to teach the conditionals, the same point could have been made with *three* digits, with much less drudgery. The only way this problem would be educational in the programming sense is if you went and programmed a code generator for it. That at least poses a nice challenge. The OP obviously is not a total noob, as his instincts (using arrays and loops) is quite on-point; why he is expected to unroll a sort manually is beyond me.

Comment: I get it, I get it, but in some circles people are pretty hard-headed about it.  One could make a hand-waving argue about how it'd give you a better appreciation later on.

Comment: @Coffee: One could also argue that [diluting dung with water in a ratio of 1:10^60 cures diseases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathic_dilutions). I don't see why I should respect those that do so. It is a good exercise for three digits. Show how easy it is for two, prompt to imagine for four -- and you also teach algorithmic complexity. There is absolutely no need, none, to actually make students do it for five.

Comment: I've been actually wondering if the numbers are inserted in an array one by one. That would simplify things a little bit.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the help anyways guys, looks like I'll just have to brute force it since there seems to be no smarter way to do it.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi: "we're not allowed to use arrays"... :(

Comment: @edkrs how are the numbers inputed? all at the same time or one by one? And can you use booleans or are those forbidden too?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi They are inputted one by one, and I asked the prof and he said that booleans hadn't been covered yet, so that's a no :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what we can do:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;
int num4 = 0;
int num5 = 0;

public class Tester {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    int num4 = 0;
    int num5 = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Tester();
    }

    public Tester(){
        checkThisNumber(5);
        checkThisNumber(6);
        checkThisNumber(3);
        checkThisNumber(4);
        checkThisNumber(2);
        System.out.println(num1);
        System.out.println(num2);
        System.out.println(num3);
        System.out.println(num4);
        System.out.println(num5);
    }

    private void checkThisNumber(int n) {
        if (n < num2) {
            num1 = n;
        } else if (n < num3) {
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = n;
        } else if (n < num4) {
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            num3 = n;
        } else if (n < num5) {
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            num3 = num4;
            num4 = n;
        } else {
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            num3 = num4;
            num4 = num5;
            num5 = n;            
        }                
    }   
}
```

That's a horribly crude sorting algorithm. If you need to make it even more simple because you can't use constructors and methods:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    int num4 = 0;
    int num5 = 0;
    int tNum1 = 5;
    int tNum2 = 6;
    int tNum3 = 3;
    int tNum4 = 4;
    int tNum5 = 2;
    num5 = tNum1;
    if (tNum2 < num5){
        num4 = tNum2;
    } else {
        num4 = num5;
        num5 = tNum2;
    }
    if (tNum3 < num4){
        num3 = tNum3;
    } else if (tNum3 < num5) {
        num3 = num4;
        num4 = tNum3;
    } else {
        num3 = num4;
        num4 = num5;
        num5 = tNum3;
    }
    if (tNum4 < num3){
        num2 = tNum4;
    } else if (tNum4 < num4){
        num2 = num3;
        num3 = tNum4;
    } else if (tNum4 < num5){
        num2 = num3;
        num3 = num4;
        num4 = tNum4;            
    } else {
        num2 = num3;
        num3 = num4;
        num4 = num5;
        num5 = tNum4;
    }
    if (tNum5 < num2){
        num1 = tNum5;
    } else if (tNum5 < num3){
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = tNum5;            
    } else if (tNum5 < num4){
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = num3;
        num3 = tNum5;
    } else if (tNum5 < num5){
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = num3;
        num3 = num4;
        num4 = tNum5;
    } else {
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = num3;
        num3 = num4;
        num4 = num5;
        num5 = tNum5;                 
    }
    System.out.println(num1);
    System.out.println(num2);
    System.out.println(num3);
    System.out.println(num4);
    System.out.println(num5);
}
```

and just for the sport, the correct solution to this is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(2);
    Collections.sort(list);
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! This was the solution I came up with also, but your code is significantly neater than mine haha

Comment: Just a note: Solution 1 and 3 ignore insertion order. While solution 2 doesn't.